# NameError: cannot load Java class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver

Tags: mysql, jdbc, jruby

I'm using JRuby 1.7.2, along with DataMapper, and I'm getting an error I can't find an answer to.

I'm just testing out DataMapper along with MySQL 5.5 to see if it will run fine when I build around it. Here's the file I'm testing:

```
require "data_mapper"
require "keys"

DataMapper.setup(:default, "mysql://#{$user}:#{$pass}@localhost/test_db")
```

And when I run this, I get the error:

```
NameError: cannot load Java class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
```

And it points to the DataMapper.setup line.

My Gemfile should be alright:

```
source :rubygems

gem "sinatra"
gem "trinidad"
gem "data_mapper"

# do a `sudo apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev` first
gem "dm-mysql-adapter"
gem "jdbc-mysql"
```

Is there anything I'm missing? I have MySQL set up with a user/pass locally already.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is a common error when running `JDBC` clients for `MySQL`. You need to make sure you have `mysql-connector-java-bin.jar` on the classpath. You can download it from [here](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/j/).

Answer (score 7):

I'm using Rails 3.2.9 and to solve the problem I added this to my application.rb

```
if defined? JRUBY_VERSION
    require 'jdbc/mysql'
    Jdbc::MySQL.load_driver
end
```

Answer (score 2):

actually, the correct answer is to work-around an incompatibility between **5.1.13** and **5.1.22** !

**jdbc-mysql** gem already contains the mysql-connector.jar it just ain't auto-loading anymore :

https://github.com/jruby/activerecord-jdbc-adapter/tree/master/jdbc-mysql (read the README)

you can also force the driver to auto-load using a Java system property e.g. from a cmd line :

`jruby -J-Darjdbc.mysql.autoload=true -S rake ...`

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error when trying to use a mysql database from jruby/rails4. In my case this line was missing from ./Gemfile:

```
gem 'jdbc-mysql'
```